# Modifying style for grouped option plugin in Highchart

Tags: highcharts, visualization, data-visualization

While trying to use https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/ i managed to get it working with an output as shown below [image: grouped options]

Is there a way that the following options can be modified
1. Removing the grids (I could manually change the stroke-width of those elements in the html to 0 to remove the grids, Is there a property / any other way available to do this?)
2. spacing between the categories
3. shifting the entire category table, so that i can insert a custom axis above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Grouped Categories plug-in documentation](https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/), you can use the `groupedOptions` property to apply your styles :

```
xAxis: {    
    labels: {
        groupedOptions: [{
            style: {
                color: 'red' // set red font for labels in 1st-Level  
            }
        }, {
            rotation: -45, // rotate labels for a 2nd-level
            align: 'right'
        }],
        rotation: 0 // 0-level options aren't changed, use them as always
    },
    categories: /* Your grouped categories */
}
```

You can therefore style almost everything you want of the `xAxis`.

**EDIT**

This will only allow you to modify the labels style. Sorry.